# Pandas: split string in a pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series `date` that looks like this:

```
date       | ...
09.01.2000 |
02.02.2000 |
...
```

The format is DD-MM-YYYY. I want to split them into three columns Day, Month and Year.
I tried:

```py
col = date["date"].str.split(".", expand = True)
date["day"] = col[0]
date["month"] = col[1]
...
```

It is quite inconvenient so is there a more pythonic way? I also tried pd.to_datetime but that is not the short way.

Comment: Convert the column in to `datetime`, that gives a lot more wonderful options for you. If you use split, it will be a string. If you convert it to `datetime`, you can do a lot of operations (ex; Groupby) without even creating new columns for date,week,year,month...etc

Comment: @moys I assume you mean a `datetime`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do multiple column assignments in a single line:

```
df[['day', 'month', 'year']] = df['date'].str.split('.', expand=True)
```

---

```
         date day month  year
0  09.01.2000  09    01  2000
1  02.02.2000  02    02  2000
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a single assignment:

```
date['date'], date['month'] = col
```

This assumes that `split()` returns a list with exactly two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['09.01.2000', '02.02.2000']})

df['mon'],df['day'],df['year'] = zip(*df['date'].str.split('.'))
print (df)
```

It will give you the below dataframe. If you don't want `df['date']`, then you can use drop() function to drop the column.

```
         date mon day  year
0  09.01.2000  09  01  2000
1  02.02.2000  02  02  2000
```